# Where is the value of timestamp come from?

Tags: javascript

The code snippet below is come from MDN (https://github.com/mdn/learning-area/blob/master/javascript/asynchronous/loops-and-intervals/simple-raf-spinner.html). I just can't understand the parameter 'timestamp' of function draw(), where is the value come from?

I tried to check it in console, rotateCount was calculated correctly, startTime is also ok, but timestamp is not defined.

```
<script>
      // Store reference to the div element, create a rotate counter and null startTime
      // and create an uninitialized variable to store the requestAnimationFrame() call in
      const spinner = document.querySelector('div');
      let rotateCount = 0;
      let startTime = null;
      let rAF;
      // Create a draw() function
      function draw(timestamp) {
        if(!startTime) {
         startTime = timestamp;
        }
        rotateCount = (timestamp - startTime) / 3;

        // If rotateCount gets over 359, set it to 'remainder of dividing by 360'
        if(rotateCount > 359) {
          rotateCount %= 360;
        }
        // Set the rotation of the div to be equal to rotateCount degrees
        spinner.style.transform = 'rotate(' + rotateCount + 'deg)';

        // Call the next frame in the animation
        rAF = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
      }
      draw();
    </script>
```

Comment: could be this? `var date = new Date(); var timestamp = date.getTime();`

Comment: Read the documentation for `requestAnimationFrame`. Says it right there in the description.

Comment: Thank you all, got it. Question closed.

Answer (score 1):

When you `console.log(timestamp)` inside the `draw()` function, you will see that the first time it gets called the timestamp is undefined but all calls after that it has a value.

This is because of the last line in the `draw()` function, which passes `draw` as a callback function to the `requestAnimationFrame()` function.

`requestAnimationFrame()` internally calls `draw()` and passes the timestamp parameter.

Answer (score 0):

According to

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

> The callback function is passed one single argument, a
>   DOMHighResTimeStamp similar to the one returned by performance.now(),
>   indicating the point in time when requestAnimationFrame() starts to
>   execute callback functions.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> function draw(timestamp) {
> ```

It's passed the first argument to `draw` whenever `draw` is called.

That's in two places:

- `draw();` where it is `undefined` *and*
- In the code underlying `requestAnimationFrame` (which is built into the browser) after you pass `draw` itself as an argument here: `requestAnimationFrame(draw)`

Answer (score 0):

Your first call to `draw()` didn't have it. But when you did this:

```
requestAnimationFrame(draw)
```

You passed `draw()` as `requestAnimationFrame()`'s callback. `requestAnimationFrame` [supplies a timestamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame#Parameters) as first argument to the callback you supply to it. Whenever it calls `draw()` for you, that's when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

See this page [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) on `window.requestAnimationFrame`, specifically this paragraph right before the first horizontal bar:

> The callback method is passed a single argument, a `DOMHighResTimeStamp`, which indicates the current time (based on the number of miliseconds since time origin). When callbacks queued by `requestAnimationFrame()` begin to fire multiple callbacks in a single frame, each receives the same timestamp even though time has passed during the computation of every previous callback's workload. This timestamp is a decimal number, in milliseconds, but with a minimal precision of 1ms (1000 µs).

So `timestamp` is passed in by the `window.requestAnimationFrame(draw)` at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

It's undefined when you call `draw()` manually. Not so when calling it inside `requestAnimationFrame` which as one passed argument as a callback (a timestamp). From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame);

> The callback method is passed a single argument, a
>   DOMHighResTimeStamp, which indicates the current time (based on the
>   number of miliseconds since time origin).